# Linking errors with fmt: undefined reference to `std::string fmt::v6::internal::grouping_impl<char>(fmt::v6::internal::locale_ref)'

Tags: c++, fmt

In our project, we decided to use the latest fmt version(6.2.0) in our project and use mainly the printf functionality as we had our logging where we are using printf extensively.

I built the libfmt.a on our Linux box using the CMakeLists.txt included in the fmt package.
In my process, I included the libfmt include directory and in the target_link_libraries. In the code I only used `#include<fmt/printf.h>`. Now when I compile the code, the code gets compiled but at the time of linking, I get the errors: There are many more but the following is the first one and I believe if this gets resolved, rest will be resolved automatically

> abc.cpp:(.text._ZN3fmt2V68internal8groupingIcEESsNS1_10locale_refE[_ZN3fmt2v68internal8groupingIcEESsNS1_10locale_refE]+0X20): undefined eference to `std::string fmt::v6::internal::grouping_impl(fmt::v6::internal::locale_ref)'

I did some analysis and found that this function's definition is present in format-inl.h. I tried including it in my code but still the same linking issue.

Now, when I defined the macro **FMT_HEADER_ONLY** in the code the linking worked.

My question is: When I am linking with the library libfmt.a, its not able to find that function. Why?
I do not want to use the header-only version.

Please let me know how to get this fixed.

Comment: How do you build your program? What libraries are you linking with? Please create a [mcve] of your `CMakeLists.txt` and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not able to replicate this issue in a small example. I tried that. My project's process is quite complex and the binary is not getting built due to this linking error, I am not able to pinpoint the code from where this function is getting called. That's why I have posted the question here to check if someone else also faced this issue and might be able to help me.

Answer (score 5):

The linkage order is important (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/471164). Make sure to pass the library after the source or object files that use it. For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
cd fmt
make fmt
cat <<EOF > test.cc
#include <fmt/printf.h>

int main() {
  fmt::printf("Hello, %s!", "world");
}
EOF
g++ test.cc -L. -lfmt -Iinclude
./a.out
```

This example fetches {fmt} from github, compiles it, creates and a small test source, compiles and runs it giving the following output:

```
Hello, world!
```

If you pass `-lfmt` before `test.cc` you'll get linkage errors.

I recommend using CMake which will take care of the linkage order for you: https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html#usage-with-cmake

Comment: Thank you for providing valuable inputs.
I forgot to mention, we are using cmake only in our project. I also thought cmake will take care of the linkage automatically. Still, let me try to shuffle the linkages and see if that resolves the issues.

Comment: Make sure to add `target_link_libraries(yourtarget fmt)`.

Comment: Yes, I did that but that did not resolve the issue. If I use the fmt in the header only mode then the compilation works. but fails with linking errors when I link with the libfmt.a

Comment: I shuffled the linkages but still not working. Please advice further.